# typedef a struct before it's declared

Tags: c, typedef

I'm not a beginner, I'm very familiar with the following idiom:

```
typedef struct Foo_ Foo;// I know typedef struct Foo Foo is fine, I'm just trying to make it clearer
struct Foo_
{
    int value;
    Foo *link;
};
```

I'm just suddenly feel confused, because  my understanding is that it's not allowed to use a name(identifier) before it's declared. But in the declaration `typedef struct Foo_ Foo`, the identifier `Foo_` does not yet exist! How come the compiler permit this happen? Would anybody please shed some light on this, explain to me what's the justification for this kind of syntax?

Wikipedia quote : The purpose of `typedef` is to assign alternative names to EXISTING types.

--- >8 ---

Thank you all guys for so much helpful information.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is completely fine. The first use of `struct` tag like yours is a forward declaration of the `struct` type.

Beware though that your usage of `_Foo` is **not** conforming. Identifiers with leading underscore and following capital letter are reserved. Don't do that. Trailing underscore would be ok.

Comment: Does that mean `typedef struct Foo_ Foo` is actually `struct Foo_; typedef struct Foo_ Foo;` merged together?

Comment: I get it, it does make sense, because we can write something like `typedef struct Foo {...} Foo;` as for `typedef struct Foo Foo;` only the `{...}` part is omitted.

Comment: Umm,Very nice thread. I get it too. So, the compiler really only the struct when see a `{` instead of `;` i.e, not really matter how many struct foo;` have only when `struct foo { ...}` the `foo` `struct` is set. The following example works fine even including `-Wall -Wextra`: `struct foo;
struct foo;

struct foo {
  int a, b, c;
  char *s;
};`

Answer (score 15):

This is covered in 6.7.2.3p8:

> #### 6.7.2.3 Tags
>
> **Semantics**
>   
>   [...]
>
> 8 - If a type specifier of the form *struct-or-union identifier* occurs other than as [a struct-or-union definition] or [a struct-or-union declaration], and no other declaration of the
>   identifier as a tag is visible, then it declares an incomplete structure or union type, and
>   declares the identifier as the tag of that type.

The type specifier `struct Foo` in `typedef struct Foo Foo` is not in a definition (`struct Foo {...};`) or a declaration (`struct Foo;`) so it falls under 6.7.2.3p8.

Note that there's nothing special about a `typedef`; you could also e.g. write

```
struct A { struct Foo *p; };
```

and a previous definition or declaration is not required to be visible.

However, in a function declaration or definition:

```
void foo(struct Foo *p);
```

if `struct Foo` is not previously declared then the *scope* of the declaration will just be the function declaration or definition, and it will not be type-compatible with any subsequent declaration or definition of `Foo`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ISO c99 : 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers
```

7

Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of
the tag in a type specifier that declares the tag.

```
typedef struct _Foo Foo; // You can do this because it's just the typedef the new type

struct _Foo *myfoo ; // It's pointer to struct _Foo (an incomplete type)
                      //but make sure before using myfoo->value   
                    // struct definition should be available

struct _Foo MyFoo;  // It's  definition of MyFoo but don't forget 
                    // to give the definition of struct _Foo (gcc extension). 

struct _Foo;  // forward declaration

struct _Foo    // It's the definition
{
    int value;
    Foo *link;
};
```

Simply as for `functions` we do `forward declaration` or `typedef` before actual definition of function , So we can do it with `struct` also.

```
void func(int );
typedef void (*func_t)(int);

void func(int x)
{
 //actual definition
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`typedef` is used to create an *alias* for a type. But that type doesn't necessarily exist when typedef'ed.

For example,

if you just do:

```
struct Foo;
```

and you never define the `struct Foo` anywhere in the program, then it'll still compile. 
Compiler would assume it's defined somewhere and continue. Only if you use it without defining the struct, an error will occur.

It's the similar case with `typedef` as well.

Comment: No. AFAIK, a `struct Foo * myFoo` would be ok, but a `struct Foo myFoo` not, because its size isn't known.

Comment: I think you mean `struct Foo;` which is a forward declaration of `Foo`

Comment: @mux It was giving you error because you have not given definition .. you can do it `struct foo myfoo;` but must provide the definition of `struct foo;` after `struct foo myfoo` declaration ; I think it may be some extension of `gcc` for struct , and also compile with `gcc` not `g++` it will compile successfully

Comment: @Omkant Incomplete type is ok whereas `struct Foo myFoo` requires complete type. `mux` was correct, but after my update his comment became obsolete which is causing the confusion now. Sorry for that :)

Comment: @KingsIndian : No no , I just went to that link which `mux` posted here and made some modifications , if please visit the link   http://ideone.com/BSOH7N and see it's working, that's my confusion ,Is standard says so or it's `gcc` extension

Comment: @Omkant but then you need a definition and it also must be in the same compilation unit (I think), the answer says if you don't define it. also I tried that with `tcc` and it fails, so it seems that gcc is doing some magic here.

Comment: @mux : yeah you are right . If we don't define struct then it's error but if definition is present in CTU then forward declaration like I said could be possible. See my answer though.I tried to convey this, but confusion is , `does standard(c99) say so`, please??

Comment: I don't have the standard to hand, but gcc 4.7 does not complain about that even with `-std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` so it's very likely to be OK (more exactly, either it's OK or gcc is buggy - use of any GNU extensions should trigger warnings with that combination of options).

Answer (score 2):

It's called forward declaring. The forward declaration allows you to use its name in context where an incomplete type is allowed.

The compiler will "see" the typedef tag, and store it away until the type is found, so as long as you have the type declared in there after the typedef, but before any usage, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Under certain circumstances, it is valid to use a `struct ...` type before it is declared. It is a so-called "incomplete type" then.

For example, it is valid to declare a variable as a pointer to an "incomplete" struct, as well as (as you can see) a `typedef`.

Answer (score -2):

**A typedef declaration lets you define your own identifiers that can be used in place of type specifiers such as int, float, and double. A typedef declaration does not reserve storage.**

for more info http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03typdef.htm

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov as u have explained in ur question my understanding is that it's not allowed to use a name(identifier) before it's declared. But in the declaration typedef struct _Foo Foo, the identifier _Foo does not yet exist! but typedef does not check for its existance..that's y i m writing the answer...try to read again & then analyse it.

Comment: I'm not the one, who posted the question, I know it's allowed to do this (there's even such example in the ISO standard), I just don't think your answer is relevant to the question.