# What type of declaration is this?

Tags: c, gcc, struct

Extending from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626246/typedef-a-struct-before-its-declared)

I am having trouble to understand this code.

```
struct foo myfoo;  // --> Is it forward declaration or object creation. ?

struct foo
{
 int a;
};

int main()
{

return 0;
}
```

In the code marked arrow `-->` Is it forward declaration or object creation. ?

If that is forward declaration then what is `struct foo;` called ? If it's object creation or instantiation then how can it create object before struct definition.

On `gcc` compiler its working fine but other compiler gives error.

```
gcc -Werror -Wall tst.c -o tst
```

Any suggestion or explanation about this behavior of `gcc`? I could not have found anywhere it as documented.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to look at the C99 standard, so I'm still not sure if it's specified somewhere, +1.

Comment: @melpomene, or maybe a feature? It seems like it is understanding that the structure is defined in the same file later on.

Comment: @mux: I looked it in standard but could not have found then posted this question .. I will have to take a look one more time

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like tentative definition of `myfoo` and because the definition of the struct is provided you get no error.

clang provides a comprehensive diagnostic when the type in not defined.

```
prasoon@ats-VPCEB3AGG:~$ cat tst.c
struct foo myfoo;

//struct foo{
//  int x ;
//} ;

int main()
{
}
prasoon@ats-VPCEB3AGG:~$ clang tst.c
tst.c:1:12: error: tentative definition has type 'struct foo' that is never
      completed
struct foo myfoo;
```

I don't think its a gcc bug, clang as well as [comeau online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) is compiling the code.

$6.9.2/2

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>      without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
>         tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>            identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>                 the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>                  identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>                   equal to 0.
>
> ---

Comment: Good catch, C99 6.9.2/2. That was a tricky one (when you're used to C++ in general).

Comment: It's funny how the standard doesn't mention struct in their example (neither in C11).

Answer (score -2):

```
 struct foo myfoo;
```

That is a C variable definition of type `foo` called `myfoo`.  C requires you to explicitly state the `struct` in front of `struct` variable declarations.

Now, your code shouldn't compile because the compiler has no idea at the place you defined your `myfoo`, what type of `foo` looks like.  The compiler should complain about `foo` being an incomplete type.

EDIT:

Scrap that, this would be called a **tentative definition**.

Comment: Tentative definitions end up "with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit" in §6.9.2/2, I believe this is what we have in the question.

Comment: What "compatibility mode"? tentative definitions are described in the C standard.