# I am trying to build a linked list using c but keep getting unknown type name:

Tags: c

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H_
#define DATABASE_H_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct TreeDataBase{
    tree_Node* root;
}tree_DB;

typedef struct tTreeNode {
    char *name;
    int tableSize;
    hash_entry** tableArray;

    tree_Node* right;
    tree_Node* left;

}tree_Node;


// hash table
//entry:
typedef struct entry_s{
    char key;
    char *value;
    hash_entry* next;

} hash_entry;
#endif
```

This is included in a database.h file
and when I try to compile it I get these Errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
unknown type name 'tree_Node'   database.h  /storage/src    line 26 C/C++    Problem
unknown type name 'tree_Node'   database.h  /storage/src    line 27 C/C++ Problem
unknown type name 'tree_Node'   database.h  /storage/src    line 18 C/C++ Problem
unknown type name 'hash_entry'  database.h  /storage/src    line 24 C/C++ P roblem
unknown type name 'hash_entry'  database.h  /storage/src    line 37 C/C++ Problem
```

Comment: You cannot refer to the typedef names _before_ they are defined.

Comment: Just define the type before defining the struct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626246/typedef-a-struct-before-its-declared

Comment: change `tree_Node* right;` to `struct tTreeNode* right;`, and ditto.

Comment: ... and move the `tree_DB`definition *after* the node definition.